# Why does Kali linux has multiple users inbuilt?

Tags: kali-linux

So I have recently downloaded Kali Linux to research on Linux Operating systems and its distributions, and I have noticed that Kali Linux comes pre installed with many users apart from 'kali' and 'root',

Why is this? Can we delete them? Or should I leave them there.

This is the output of `cat /etc/passwd`:

[image]

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: When the command 'cat /etc/passwd' is used the command line shows a list of users, I am asking what is the importance of these users, and can we delete them?

Comment: I have added an image from the google about what results are shown, you can see the examples over there

Comment: See this question on U&L SE: [Why are there many accounts? I'm the only user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197124/108618).